# Comparing two files using bash script

Tags: bash, scripting, file

I need a script to edit files. Im going a bit crazy about this already :).

I've got two files:

```
143956;lorem 
143957;ipsum
143958;lala
143959;vuvu
```

and second

```
512;143956;15
2156;143957;15
153;143958;4968
2156;143959;486
```

And what I need is to put those two files together in this way:

```
512;143956;lorem;15
2156;143957;ipsum;15
153;143958;lala;4968
2156;143959;vuvu;486
```

That doesn't look that difficult and probably `paste` would be enough, but theres a catch. There are rows which are only in one of those files but aren't in the other. In such case I need to wait on the line on the second file and still comparing to the first.

Example:

```
143956;lorem 
143957;ipsum
143959;vuvu //here "lulu" is missing, will compare with 3rd line (143958) but the script wont declare this as "not found" but keep on searching till finds 143959 (which is already on 4 in this case).

 512;143956;15 
 2156;143957;15  
 153;143958;4968
 2156;143959;486
```

The output would look like this then:

```
512;143956;lorem;15
2156;143957;ipsum;15
2156;143959;vuvu;486
```

Or better this way

```
512;143956;lorem;15
2156;143957;ipsum;15
153;143958;*WAS NOT FOUND*;4968
2156;143959;vuvu;486
```

But I can finish that on my own...

Hope this is understandable. Thanks very much for any help.

Comment: Thanks for posting your example input including an edge case. Could you also post the expected output for this case?

Comment: Does it have to be in `bash` or could we switch to a proper programming language like python?

Comment: Thanks for reply Mark, I edited the question including the edge case output.

Comment: It can be done in anything I can ran I think, I am just trying to learn something new in bash, but wont mind any working solutions :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Bash process substitution (`<()`) and the [`join`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/join) utility:

```
join -t \; -1 1 -2 2 -o 2.1,2.2,1.2,2.3 <(sort file1) <(sort -t \; -k2,2 file2)
```

Or you can presort the files.

To output the records that appear in file2 but don't appear in file1:

```
join -t \; -1 1 -2 2 -v 2 -o 2.1,2.2,1.2,2.3 <(sort file1) <(sort -t \; -k2,2 file2) | sed 's/;;/;*WAS NOT FOUND*;/'
```

Comment: Great, it looks like its working! I am gonna try it fully tomorrow - need some sleep now. But it looks really great. Thanks

Comment: Theres just one think I am getting double \n over there, because we are using the end parts in both of the files, can I get rid of that?

Comment: @aGr: Can you explain more about what's in the source data and the result that is related to the problem? Where are the extra newlines in the output? What does "using the end parts in both of the files" mean? Is this happening using both of the commands I gave or if only one, which one?

Answer (score 1):

If the first file isn't too large, you can do (`test1` and `test2` are two files in the order you specified):

```
#!/bin/sh

for line in `cat test2`; do
  number=`echo "$line" | grep -o ";[0-9]*;" | sed 's/;//g'`
  repl=`grep "$number;" test1`
  if [ -z "$repl" ]; then
    echo "$line" | sed "s#;$number;#;$number;*WAS NOT FOUND*;#g"
  else
    echo "$line" | sed "s#;$number;#;$repl;#g"
  fi  
done
```

Comment: Unfortunatly it is - about 30 Mb. I am getting this error "./sc: 11: sed: Argument list too long" when I sorted the files. Before when I didnt I got some results, but it wrote a different message - I can write it here but sorting it is the right thing anyway, or isnt it?

Comment: Although the data in the question doesn't contain any spaces, it's a bad habit to use `for $(cat file)` because this will break each word onto a separate line. The correct way to do this is `while read -r line; do ... done < file`. And you're right about large files. Calling that many utilities on each line in a file could be incredibly slow. Also, you've got `$number` twice. There should be two different ones. That would mean yet another `echo|grep|sed`. And yet another one to parse the needed string from `test1`.